# Kerning/font-tracking issue in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have created a basic RDLC report in Visual Studio 2010.  In the report designer it looks fine, and when I use the report viewer to view the report it also looks fine.  However, once I send the report to a printer, there seems to be an issue with the kerning or tracking, such that there are no spaces between characters, and all the letters are somewhat wider than they should be.  Has anyone come across this before and if so, do you know how to fix it?